# SimpleXML: Finding a parent node key/ID based on a child node value

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I am trying to use a SimpleXML solution to find a specific value of a one child node to change another child node on the same level. I just tried to do it that way:

- find a value
- find a parent "id/key"
- find (and replace) another child on this parent.

Can you help me how to make it properly in PHP?

This is my example XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<products>
    <product>
        <local_id>1234</local_id>
        <product_code>PRODUCT1</product_code>
        <available>100</available>
        <price>30</price>
    </product>
    <product>
        <local_id>1235</local_id>
        <product_code>PRODUCT2</product_code>
        <available>50</available>
        <price>45</price>
    </product>
</products>
```

I know that I can do it in two different ways, but do not know which is more efficient.

Algorithm A:
I want to replace child-node `<price>` (which is changing daily) with another value based on `<local_id>` as below

- find child-node `<local_id> = 1235`
- find key/ID of a parent-node `<product>` with child-node found above
- replace value of another child-node (`<price>`) from 45 to i.e. 20

Algorithm B:
Because one product with its ID has only one price I want to find a child-node `<price>` on the same level as child-node `<local_id>` and replace value as below

- find a child-node `<local_id> = 1235`
- find a child-node `<price>` on the same level
- replace child-node (`<price>`) from 45 to i.e. 20.

I have searched everywhere, but some solutions are similar but not about my case (searching on the same level or finding parent based on child to find another child).

Thank you in advance!

PS - Question rebuilt to be more correct with rules and for clearance. Sorry for a mess at the beginning :)

Comment: Please, take some time to read [how to ask](/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: This part of your question isn't clear: `Eventually (if it is possible) I would like to find a child (<local_id> = 1235) and replace another child on equal level as this one ( = 35).` You may want to trim down this question to only the first part and when  you get an answer, post another one with the "eventually" question.

Comment: I found two ways to do the same, but asking for a better solution for both cases leading me to the same effect.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [$xml->xpath()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php), something like the following should work

```
$xmlstr ='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<products>
    <product>
        <local_id>1234</local_id>
        <product_code>PRODUCT1</product_code>
        <available>100</available>
        <price>30</price>
    </product>
    <product>
        <local_id>1235</local_id>
        <product_code>PRODUCT2</product_code>
        <available>50</available>
        <price>45</price>
    </product>
</products>';

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstr);
$node = $xml->xpath('//products/product/local_id[text()="1235"]/parent::*')[0];
$node->price=99;
echo $xml->asXML();
```

In the above example, I replace the price value to verify that is the correct node.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! Unfortunately I am not finding the right child-node and can not display it and replace - it's not working for me that way :(

Comment: Don't know if you just copy and paste, but I see that in local_id value i putted an extra space. Anyway, it is a matter of xpath pattern

Comment: Sorry my xpath was completely wrong, never answer on late night :-), I corrected the answer